# Can we use libGDX for rendering models instead of OpenGL in ARcore?

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, arcore

I am trying to build small app which basically detect a plane using ARCore and place some 3D model on that plane. I have seen Sample code of ARCore and it requires too much boiler plate code to render model using openGL. So I was wondering can we use libGDX for rendering. I tried searching sample project but did not find any.I don't want to use unity keeping APK size constrain in mind. I am new to these things and any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked into using ARCore and LibGDX and built a little sample.  It's a little long to post as an answer but the highlights are:

- Extend AndroidApplication to add the Activity level ARCore calls to initialize the Session, get the permissions for the camera.
- Extend AndroidGraphics to integrate the ARCore render loop.
- Extend ApplicationListener to overload a render method to pass in the ARCore Frame, so rendering has access to the ARCore information.

I shared my project at https://github.com/google/helloargdx.